# Grails 2.4.0 - Error: ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.spock.test.GrailsSpecTestType

Tags: grails, classnotfoundexception, spock

Whenever I enter the grails command: `test-app` I get this error:

`Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.spock.test.GrailsSpecTestType (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`

In my BuildConfig.groovy I have:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    ...
    plugins {
        ...
        compile ":spock:0.7"
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing it with `test ":spock:0.7"` . I've also tried cleaning the application and refreshing the dependencies but no luck.

Any ideas what it could be and how I could fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the newest version of Grails? 2.4.3? They fixed many bugs!

Comment: I've got the same problem. But I'm running grails 2.3.9. Do you know what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Grails 2.4.0 you don't need to make any mention of Spock in BuildConfig.groovy.  See the sample project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/spockdemo.

When you can, you should look at upgrading to the latest in the 2.4.x line.  A number of issues have been addressed since 2.4.0 was released.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank for the input. Unfortunately, the code I am using is not compatible with the latest version of Grails, so upgrading is not an option. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The project I linked above shows how to do this with 2.4.0.  You don't need to make any mention of Spock in your BuildConfig.groovy.

Answer (score 1):

@zzKozak is correct - you should upgrade. It has no bearing here, but getting to the latest version of Grails within your minor version (in this case 2.4.3) should happen before you ask others for help with issue that could have been fixed youself with a simple upgrade.

In 2.4, Grails switched to Spock tests by default, and you have to uninstall the old plugin since they're incompatible. Delete that line in BuildConfig.groovy and change your base classes to core the new Grails/Spock base classes. For integration queries, use `grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec`. For unit tests and more information about this, check out the testing section in the docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html

Comment: "a simple upgrade" is not necessarily simple in an Enterprise environment.  You're not being realistic.